# timeout doesn't work with nvm: nvm no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, timeout, nvm

I want to set timeout for each instance of node.js running. but when I run the following commands I got the error `timeout: failed to run command ‘nvm’: No such file or directory`:

```
timeout 10 nvm run 17.9.0 file1.js 
timeout 5 nvm run 17.1.0 file2.js
```

but running the below commands ends without any error or problem:

```
timeout 10 ping 8.8.8.8

nvm run 17.9.0 file1.js
```

what is the matter?

Comment: Can you please compare the ouput of `which nvm` and `timeout 5 which nvm`?

Comment: `timeout` can only be used with external commands. Use `type nvm` to see what your `nvm` is. It may be a shell function or alias.

Comment: @Markus the output of `which nvm` is a code and the output of `timeout 5 which nvm` is empty

Comment: @thatotherguy the output of `type nvm` is `nvm is a shell function from /root/.nvm/nvm.sh`. so it means I can't use it with timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the `nvm` command in interactive shell:

```
timeout 10 bash -ic "nvm run 17.9.0 file1.js"
```